# iOS make universal app for iPhone 4 and 5

Tags: ios, storyboard

Quick question. For iOS in Xcode I want to make an app that looks good on the iPhone 5 and the iPhone 4. I am using story boards. All I know is when you click the button on the bottom of the storyboard page with the two arrows on both sides of an iPhone it changes the views of the app from 4 inch to 3.5 or vise versa. This usually makes it look messed up because if I made the app with an iPhone 5 screen it looks weird on the iPhone 4 screen. Preferably without using code and just using storyboards, how do I make an app that is universal for the iPhone 4 and the iPhone 5. Basically like making an app universal for the iPhone and iPad where there are 2 storyboards (one for the iPhone and one for the iPad) how do I do that for the iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 (one story board for the 4 inch screen and one for the 3.5 inch screen)?

Thank you

Comment: A better approach is try try and do it with auto layout constraints.  They are a bit of a learning curve and can be frustrating, but they allow you to specific the relationship between UI elements.  Using constraints also makes your app more flexible so that it will cope if Apple releases a new device with a different resolution.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/jack-cox/ios-7-tutorial-series-auto-layout-xcode-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use autolayouts to format your views.

Those arrows are only to simulate the view. They are not view holders.

Check: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html